# What is the expression for $f_{*}X$, where $f:R^{3}\to R^{4}$ is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry

If $f:(x,y,z)\to (xy, 2xz, xy-2z,z)$ is an immersion from $R^{3}$ to $R^{4}$. Is then a vector $f_{*}X = xye_{1}+2xze_{2}+(xy-2z)e_{3}+ze_{4}$, for $X=xe_{1}+ye_{2}+ze_{3}$ in $M$ and $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\}$, $\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3},e_{4}\}$ basis of $R^{3}$ and $R^{4}$, respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, calculate the $4\times 3$  Jacobian matrix of your map (my apologies, I don't know how to enter a matrix; I will go thru some posts to figure it out; please give me a few minutes):

Calculate the Jacobian matrix $J_{ik}$ of $f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),...,f_4(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ by

{$j_{ik}$ }  $:=\partial f_i/\partial x^k$

(Sorry, I pasted a matrix for another post and tried to imitate the output , but I could not get it right)

Then use this to calculate the pushforward of your respective tangent vectors; let me
 redefine your {$e_1,e_2,e_3$} as {$e_x,e_y,e_z$} and {${e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4}$} as {${e_x',e_y',e_z',e_w'}$}:

$f_*(e_x)= ye_x'+2ze_y'+ye_z'$

$f_*(e_y)= xe_x'+xe_z'$

$f_*(e_z)= 2xe_y'+e_w'$

Now use linearity of $f_*$ to find the pushforward of any other vector.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be getting confused between tangent vectors and points.

Write a vector $X$ based at the point $(x,y,z)$ as $X = \sum_{j=1}^3 X^j e_j$. Then

$$ 
f_* X = \sum_{j=1}^3 X^j \partial_j f
= X^1 (y e_1 + 2z e_2 + y e_3) + X^2 (x e_1 + x e_3) + X^3 (2x e_2 - 2 e_3 + e_4).
$$